# Calculating Hodge numbers by means of locally free resolutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801092v1.pdf) the author considers a smooth $3$-fold $X$ in $\Bbb{CP}^6$ with the following locally free resolutions of its structure sheaf and squared ideal sheaf:

$$0\to \mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-7) \to 7\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-4)\to 7\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-3)\to\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}\to \mathcal O_X\to 0$$
$$0\to 21\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-8)\to 48\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-7)\to 28\mathcal O_\Bbb {P^6}(-6)\to \mathcal I_X^2\to 0$$

He immediately deduces the Hodge numbers and canonical sheaf of $X$ from these exact sequences together with the connormal bundle and Euler exact sequences, obtaining that $X$ is Calabi Yau with $h^{1,1}=1, h^{1,2}=50$.

Apparently, he uses some standard techniques which I'm not familiar with. Could anyone explain his method to me?

Comment: The article you cite is a short version of his PhD thesis. Here's a link to his full thesis, in which he proves this in much more detail.  The trick is to use the standard exact sequences relating $\Omega_X$ to $\Omega_{\mathbb P}$ and $\mathbb I/I^2$. http://folk.uio.no/einarro/Projects/Previous/thesis.pdf